# Bundling ruby-oci8 on Heroku needs LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, heroku, buildpack

I'd like to use the gem 'ruby-oci8' in my Heroku ruby app.

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'sinatra'
```

This fails when bundler tries to build ruby-oci8 because the oracle client libraries can't be found.  I looked around and found https://github.com/nasali/oracle-oci8-heroku-buildpack.  It doesn't exactly work as-advertised, if at all.

Inspired, I figured the way to solve this problem would be to use multiple buildpacks, one to pull the necessary libraries and setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and then followed by the regular heroku-buildpack-ruby buildpack which would build ruby-oci8.

I created my own Heroku buildpack [oracle-heroku-buildpack](https://github.com/karneyli/oracle-heroku-buildpack) where I extract the required oracle libraries to `#{BUILD_DIR}/vendor/oracle_instantclient` and then try to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that when the normal heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby buildpack runs after to build ruby-oci8, the libraries would be found.  Alas, the latter part is near impossible!

It seems that setting `config_vars` during compile/release phase of the buildpack or using `.profile.d` is useless to my scenario because these aren't run until after all the compile steps of all buildpacks are completed.  I need LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to where the oracle libraries can be found **before** heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby executes.

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=vendor/oracle_instantclient` using `heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=vendor/oracle_instantclient` doesn't seem to work either, it doesn't resolve to the temporary build directory properly during compilation of ruby-oci8.

I think, if I could set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the temporary `#{BUILD_DIR}/vendor/oracle_instantclient` somehow, that would work. Any ideas?

It seems like environment variables between buildpacks doesn't modify the global environment variable, or at least I haven't figure out how.

Comment: I figured out how to do it.  To pass environment variables from one buildpack to another all I needed to do was write to the `ENV_DIR` a file named after the env var key I wanted to set and the contents of the file being the value.

Comment: I realized this under https://github.com/wealthsimple/oracle-heroku-buildpack if anyone ever needs to use Oracle + Ruby + Heroku